# Удалить пробелы в конце каждой строчки, до переноса

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

https://regex101.com/r/PtkGM1/1

Не выходит, первый пустые строчки удалим, ок. Но как оставить те 2 пробела, в начале первой строчки с текстом?

```
[\s]+\n
```

Так я пытаюсь найти все пробелы которые есть перед переносом строчки. Как я понимаю, в данном случаи я удалю так же перенос в конце каждой строчки. Вопрос в том, как не удалять перенос строчки?

```
$tx = '
  
  
   текст       
    текст       


     текст            
      текст    

  
';



print_r("<div style='display: -webkit-box; white-space: pre-wrap;word-break: break-word;'>".preg_replace('#(^[\s\n]+|[\s\n]+$)#s', null, $tx)."</div>");
```

**Как мне удалить пробелы в конце каждой строчки и при этом сохранить переносы?**

Comment: Формулируйте задачу, а не только попытку её решить.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/y8d5qY/1 Как удалить все пробелы в каждой строчке перед переносом строки и при этом сохранить переносы? Если возможно удалить еще пустые строчки в начале и в конце.

Comment: Так оно работает, только вместе с этим удаляет переносы строчек в тексте, пустые строчки по центру...

Comment: Да у Вас вообще регулярка ничего не изменяет, она только ищет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\s` эквивалентно `[\r\n\t\f\v ]` и уже включает в себя перевод строки.
Когда выполняется замена то ограничитель `\n` для выбора пробелов так же удаляется.

---

Попробуйте использовать в выражении только горизонтальные `\h` пробельные символы и символ конца строки `$`:

```
\h+$
```

Либо использовать позитивный просмотр вперед на перенос строки или  конец текста

```
\h+(?=\n|\Z)
```

Пример: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/nSshvf/1)

UPD: Для preg_replace

```
$reg = '/\h+$/m';
$tx = '
   текст       
    текст       


     текст            
      текст    

  ';
$substr = "";
$result = preg_replace($reg, $substr, $tx);
echo $result;
```

Comment: `preg_replace('#\h+$#gm', null, $tx)` В примере работает на ура, вот подставляю в preg_replace, не выходит. Просто весь текст удалят, с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: @Лена, думаю что проблема в том, что в preg_replace отсутствует модификатор `g`, а глобальность замены установлена по умолчанию в четвертом параметре `-1`